# Webpage gets slow after updating the DOM repeatedly through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a main webpage, and a container div inside it. Everytime the user clicks on an menu element of the main page, its child `div` gets loaded with a HTML page, containing references to JavaScript libraries and some form elements according to the functionality needed this way:

```
function loadGame(idGame) {

    var nom = "";

    switch (parseInt(idGame, 10)) {
        case 7:
            nom = "g7/game7.html"
            break;
        case 2:
            nom = "g2/game2.html"
            break;
        case 6:
            nom = "g6/game6.html"
            break;
        case 8:
            nom = "g8/game8.html"
            break;
        case 4:
            nom = "g4/game4.html"
            break;
        case 9:
            nom = "g9/game9.html"
            break;
    }

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: nom,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {                
                $('#divPag').empty();
                $('#divPag').html(data);
            } ,
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                //alert('exception: ' + exception + '|' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
    });    

}
```

Happens that if the user clicks around different menu elements too many times, the whole page starts to get slower and slower due to the memory getting bloated as for what Chrome Task Manager reports (reaching 100 000 KB for example).

I thought that `$('#divPag').empty();` would remove the child nodes and its previously set event handlers safely to avoid this but apparently is not.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?. I appreciate your insight on this issue.

Comment: Just an fyi, with what you are doing you don't need to `.empty()` since you are doing `$('#divPag').html(data);` anyways

Comment: And, just to be clear, both `.html(data)` and `.empty()` do correctly unbind all *jquery bound event handlers and jquery data* for the elements contained within. The only thing that remains is the cache of selectors used to build dom nodes. `$.cache`

Comment: `[...] with a HTML page, containing references to JavaScript libraries [...]` so the pages you load contain `script` tags?  What libraries are you referencing/loading there?

Comment: Thanks guys, and yes @t.niese, they do contain script tags (referred as "JavaScript libraries" on my post).

Comment: @CoderRoller the libraries will then be loaded multiple times (the script is loaded, executed and stored in memory everytime), depending on how the js engine of the browser handles this and how the libraries work, they will last in memory until you refresh the page. If you also load `jquery` there with `script` tags then the whole thing gets even worser.

Comment: move your script tags to outside #divPag to avoid needless reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the advice received and some aditional reading, I changed the approach of how I am loading each game page.

Now when the user clicks on a certain game link, I reload the whole page adding a querystring parameter with the idGame on the URL, then I get the it through JavaScript and I call the `function loadGame(idGame)` via `$(document).ready` afterwards and I also hook up my game links to the function that reloads the whole page with the new parameter on it.

This way I don't need to rearrange the scripts references to the main page or tackle the whole code to optimize it and free the references to variables, objects, and scripts to let the JavaScript Garbage Collector act on them. Since the libraries are just loaded once after each page reload everything that happened before is wiped out from the memory.

To simulate smoothness I am now preloading the images and I am also hiding the container div content till the whole game is loaded.

Thanks again people.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing 10 times , will call 10 ajax calls, (remember ajax calls ares asynchronous))) , so either block ui, until the call is finished , or kill all current calls after a new press of menu button. make you ajax call global , and then call .abort() before sending new one.